# Save bundle to file

Tags: android

```
  Bundle bundle;
  //set data to bundle
  //......


  File file = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()  + "/data/");
                FileOutputStream fos;
                try {
                     fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                     //fos.write
                     fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException exp1) {
                    exp1.printStackTrace();
                } catch ( IOException exp2) {
                    exp2.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I have the aforementioned code. All I want to do is to save the bundle to the file. I found the method write but I can't pass there a bundle but only a byte[].I tried to convert the bundle to byte[] but I didn't succeed it. What Should I do to make this work? What is the most efficient way?

Comment: Why are you trying to write the bundle to file? Instead why not write the data of the bundle to the file?

Comment: explain why do you need this.

Answer (score 5):

There is no general way to save and restore bundle from persistent storage. This is because Parcel class doesn't give any android version compatibility guarantee. So we better not serialize it.

But if you really want you can searialize Bundle via Parceable interface. Convert bundle to a Parcel (writeToParcel()/readFromParcel()), then use Parcel's marshall() and unmarshall() methods to get a byte[]. Save/Load byte Array to file. But there is a chance, that one day you wont be able to restore your data in case user updates his Android OS to a newer version.

There is one legal but very paifull and unreliable way to serialize bundle using ObjectOutput/InputStream. (get all keys, iterate through keys and save serializable key=value pairs to a file, then read key=value pair from file, determine value's type, put data back in Bundle via appropriate putXXX(key, value) method) But it is not worth it )

I suggest you to put your custom serializable structure in Bundle to store all required values in it and save/load from file only this structure.

Or find a better way to manage your data without using Bundle.

Comment: You should never do it. From `Parcel.marshall()` documentation *The data you retrieve here must not be placed in any kind of persistent storage (on local disk, across a network, etc). For that, you should use standard serialization or another kind of general serialization mechanism. The Parcel marshalled representation is highly optimized for local IPC, and as such does not attempt to maintain compatibility with data created in different versions of the platform.*

Comment: @vmironov so, what do you suggest for the serialization?

Comment: Yeah, if user sometimes update android version there is a chance that you wont be able to restore parcel. So do not save critical data this way )

Answer (score 4):

I didn't like the formatting of the code in my comment above, so this is how you would read it back out:

Read it like this:

```
try {
    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(localFilename);
    byte[] array = new byte[(int) fis.getChannel().size()];
    fis.read(array, 0, array.length);
    fis.close();
    parcel.unmarshall(array, 0, array.length);
    parcel.setDataPosition(0);
    Bundle out = parcel.readBundle();
    out.putAll(out);
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
} catch (IOException ioe) {
} finally {
    parcel.recycle();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the `setDataPosition()` hint! Who could know it has to be called!

Comment: Don't do it. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html says "it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage"

Answer (score 3):

```
Bundle in=yourBundle;
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(localFilename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Parcel p = Parcel.obtain(); //creating empty parcel object
in.writeToParcel(p, 0); //saving bundle as parcel 
fos.write(p.marshall()); //writing parcel to file
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Comment: i am sorry it was my mistake its was parcel object into which we are saving our bundle.

Comment: Read it like this:

    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(localFilename);

    byte[] array = new byte[(int) fis.getChannel().size()];

    fis.read(array, 0, array.length);

    fis.close();

    parcel.unmarshall(array, 0, array.length);

    parcel.setDataPosition(0);

    Bundle out = parcel.readBundle();

    out.putAll(out);

    parcel.recycle();

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
public void write(String fileName, Bundle bundle)
    {
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File outDir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "My Bundle");
        if (!outDir.isDirectory())
        {
            outDir.mkdir();
        }
        try
        {
            if (!outDir.isDirectory())
            {
                throw new IOException("Unable to create directory My bundle. Maybe the SD card is mounted?");


    }
        File outputFile = new File(outDir, fileName);
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
        String value=bundle.getString("key");
        writer.write(value);
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Report successfully saved to: " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.w("error", e.getMessage(), e);
        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage() + " Unable to write to external storage.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Here, the idea is simple. You pass the `Bundle` to this method and then extract whatever data you have in that (Example in this case we have a string with the key `key`) and then  write that to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Here are function that can help you convert a `Bundle` to a `JSONObject`, note that it will only work if the bundle contains `int`s and `String`s only

```
public static JSONObject bundleToJsonObject(Bundle bundle) {
    try {
        JSONObject output = new JSONObject();
        for( String key : bundle.keySet() ){
            Object object = bundle.get(key);
            if(object instanceof Integer || object instanceof String)
                    output.put(key, object);
            else
                throw new RuntimeException("only Integer and String can be extracted");
        }
        return output;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static Bundle JsonObjectToBundle(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    try {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject.keys();
        while( keys.hasNext() ){
            String key = (String)keys.next();
            Object object = jsonObject.get(key);
            if(object instanceof String)
                bundle.putString(key, (String) object);
            else if(object instanceof Integer)
                bundle.putInt(key, (Integer) object);
            else
                throw new RuntimeException("only Integer and String can be re-extracted");
        }
        return bundle;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save a bundle in to local file. You will get Non Serialization Exception. There may be other shortcuts to store. After reading and constructing the original object is not 100% assured.

Answer (score 0):

I thing the best idea is static serializable or everything, as Bundle is iterable from keys, serialized and unserialized on another side, you can use then json, or anything. For example, if You will use the same class in server and receiver, ...

bundle->serializable_object->json->file->serializable_object->bundle

any os version guaranted working